# Rxjava Observe stream as List for Specific time

Tags: android, arraylist, listener, rx-java, rx-java2

### What i am trying to do ?

I have an observable(dayListener) that emits 100 - 300 items(not confirmed maybe return nothing) from server first time I subscribe to it, then it returns 1 item after 1 hour. each Item is of type **UserData**

### What is Problem?

I want to Observe item from (dayListner) for 3 seconds and convert it to List and store it , then later on keep on observing same observable for single item **UserData**

### My Attempt

I cannot figure out how to convert observable for 3 seconds in rxjava 2 , because I can't return two types for same observable , **UserData** and **List** , so i am unable to form solution any ideas really appreciated !! , I'm just newbie to **rxjava 2**

Comment: Did you check the [Buffer operator](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/buffer.html)?

Comment: yes i did check that operator , but confusion is what about when i am observing single item after getting list of first emitted items , and buffer is risky operator it discards items sometimes

Comment: Well, you simply can't. An `Observable` emits a single type so you can't emit both a list and a simple item. You have some workarounds like emitting lists of a single item or emit something like an [Either](https://github.com/MarioAriasC/funKTionale/wiki/Either) of a list or an item

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply use 2 different Observables, you're wanting to listen for 2 different types of data anyways.

First Observable should have a limit of 3 seconds:

`firstListObservable = userSourceObservable
  .takeUntil(Observable.timer(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS))
  .toList()`

And then you have the Observable for the rest of the values:

`remainingValuesObservable = userSourceObservable
  .skipUntil(Observable.timer(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS))`

Was this what you wanted?

Comment: thanks that gave me an excellent idea for how to handle such situation

Answer (score 1):

You could create a Pair class and use Zip operator to merge both result in one emmited Item

```
class Pair {
        String a;
        Integer b;

        Pair(String a, Integer b) {
            this.a = a;
            this.b = b;
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void testZipDifferentTypes() {
        Observable.zip(obA(), obB(), Pair::new)
                .subscribe(System.out::println);
    }

    private Observable<String> obA() {
        return Observable.just("hello");
    }

    private Observable<Integer> obB() {
        return Observable.just(1);
    }
```